# MissingResourceException - Can't find bundle for base name

Tags: java, properties, struts2, locale, bundle

I know that there are a lot of questions and answers exactly about this error on stackoverflow and other forums. But I still can not find the solution...

For speed reasons I have one utility class which loads all static data maps (for example months) depending on locale provided.

So this utility class looks something like this:

```
public static final String GLOBAL_MESSAGES = "globalMessages";

private static Map<Integer,Month> monthsMap;

private ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(Locale locale) {
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(GLOBAL_MESSAGES, locale);
    return rb;
}

private Map<Integer,Month> getMonths() {
    if(monthsMap == null) {
        setMonths();
    }
    return monthsMap;
}

private void setMonths() {
    try {
        monthsMap = getFactory().getDAO().getAllMonths();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } catch (EmptyResultException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
}

public Map<Integer,Month> getMonths(Locale locale) {
    if(locale == null) {
        return monthsMap;
    } else {
        if(this.locale != locale) {
            this.locale = locale;
            setMonths();
        }
    }
    ResourceBundle rb = getResourceBundle(locale);
    Map<Integer,Month> map = new HashMap<Integer, Month>();
    for(Month akVO : getMonths().values()) {
        try {
            akVO.setName(rb.getString(akVO.getName()));
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            //already done
        }
        map.put(akVO.getId(), akVO);
    }       
    return map;
}
```

Files globalMessages.properties (globalMessages_en_US.properties,...) are directly in source package *resources*. When deployed on Tomcat there are in folder *WEB-INF/classes*.

Now the problem. **It all works when working in this application**. But I have another application which connects throught REST API (JAX-RS) to this one. When making a request *App/rest/months.xml* I get the following error:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name globalMessages, locale en_us
```

I am really lost. And desperate...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok... Found the error. After one f* day... The problem is in case sensitive letters. Even though, when setting the locale from rest with "en_US" somehow ResourceBundle (when going through REST) is looking for "en_us".

**EDIT**:
Ok, found also the error why it was all in small letters.
Problem was, because I was creating locale with:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
```

instead of:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en","US");
```

Comment: :) I have to like your comment :)

Comment: You helped me out.  I was using Locale.getDefault() which worked well in Eclipse and in the WAS container but not when I went to a UNIX box. Thanks!

Comment: The worse thing is that on Mac (dev machine) works ok because the file lookup seems to be case insensitive, but when moved to a Linux production box it stops working.

Comment: Plus one. An oldie, but still a useful goodie. Have a Nice Answer badge.

Comment: FUUUUUUU***! Same problem, lost HOURS.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody having trouble with a Glassfish server in this case, there is the possibility to set the Locale within the Admin Overview

[image]

Simple overwrite the default locale as shown in the picture

Somebody might find this useful, I had trouble for multiple hours and dont want anyone to have this kind of problem aswell